# Remove Dot from phone number

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro/tablou-definitivi']
    page_number = 1
    
    def parse(self, response):
        base_url='https://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro'
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        tra = soup.find_all('div',class_='panel-title')
        productlinks=[]
        for links in tra:
            for link in links.find_all('a',href=True)[1:]:
                comp=base_url+link['href']
                yield Request(comp, callback=self.parse_book)
     
    
    def parse_book(self, response):
           
        # header=response.xpath("//div[@class='av_bot_left left']")
        # for k in header:
        #     title=k.xpath("//h1//text()").get()
        #     title=title.strip()
        #     dec=k.xpath("//p[@class='ral_r f16']//text()").get()
        #     dec=dec.strip()
                
        d1=''
        d2=''
        d3=''
        d4=''
        d5=''
        
        detail=response.xpath("//div[@class='av_bot_left left']//p")
        for i in range(len(detail)):
           
              if 'Decizia de intrare:' in detail[i].get():
                d1=detail[i].xpath('.//text()').getall()
            
                d1 = [i.strip() for i in d1 if i.strip()][-1]
                print(d1)
                
                
              elif 'Telefon:' in detail[i].get():
                d2=detail[i].xpath('.//text()').getall()
                d2 = [i.strip() for i in d2 if i.strip()][-1]
                print(d2)
```

This is my output. I want to remove the dot from the phone number and replace 0 With `+`. This is the page link https://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro/avocat/15655/aanegroae-ana-maria

```
0752.172.817
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
+752 172 817
```

Comment: did you tried 'txt.replace("."," ")' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` function to solve the part of changing dots by spaces, also you need to slice the first character of the string to remove the first zero:

```
out = "0752.172.817"
out = "+ " + out[1:].replace(".", " ")
print(out)
```

**Note** that you must not use `replace()` to remove the first zero as the phone number could contain a zero and be replaced by a `+` character

Output:

```
+ 752 172 817
```

Comment: where I can add these line in my code

Comment: @amen-aziz Wherever you have the phone number string variable

Comment: these is phone number part                                                                                           
                 `elif 'Telefon:' in detail[i].get():
                 d2=detail[i].xpath('.//text()').getall()
                 d2 = [i.strip() for i in d2 if i.strip()][-1]
                 print(d2)`

Comment: @amen-aziz Then you must replace `print(d2)` by the corresponding operations made on my answer, where I used `out` variable. For example, `d2 = "+ " + d2[1:].replace(".", " ")`

Comment: they show these error

Comment: d2 = "+ " + d2[1:].replace(".", " ")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: can you find any way how to solve?

Comment: @amen-aziz I need more information about the request argument that you add to the functions of your class, please update your question with full functional code

Comment: these will work `d2 = [i.strip().replace(".", " ") for i in d2 if i.strip()][-1]` and comma are remove but now problem is that how I replace 0 with + sign

Comment: @amen-aziz Please use string slicing after doing loop comprehension. `d2 = "+" + d2[1:]`, but d2 must be a string. Make sure the d2 variable is able to perform slicing in that way. if it doesn't work, try with `d2[0] = "+" + d2[0][1:]`

Comment: how apply for loop on these `d2[0] = "+" + d2[0][1:]`  some has three or four phone number

Comment: like these `+236 493 440; 0314 380 684;` they apply on one but not adding + sign on other number

Comment: @amen-aziz Please open another question instead of using comments on this one. It looks like what you are referring to is not the same as the main topic of this specific question.